# How to add a segmented control anchored to the bottom of the screen below a table view in interface builder

Tags: ios

I have a view controller (derived from UIViewController not UITableViewController) containing a table view. The controller and view are both within the same xib.

I want to add a segmented control to appear at the bottom of the screen, with the table view taking up the rest of the space above it.
However in IB it will not let me place the segmented control as a direct child of the view controller, it will only let me place it as a child of the table view i.e. the hierarchy looks like this:

Navigation Controller
    Navigation Bar
    Main View Controller - Item
        Table View
            Segmented Control - First, Second
        Navigation Item - Item
            Bar Button Item - Style

If I run it like this then the segmented control floats up and down depending upon how many items there are in the table view.

What can I do to get it to be locked to the bottom of the screen?

UPDATE:
I got nearer - I added a view as a child of the main view controller and made the table view and segment control children of that, but now only the top half of the control appears when I run the simulator but everything looks fine in IB, why is there a discrepency?

Side question - as a starting point I'm using one of Apple's sample project, why was there no main view? When should you and when should you not have a main view?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just open your xib and expand your view and drag Tableview control under View and also drag segmented control under view not in tablview this will work.

you need to set frame of both in you viewDidLoad

```
tblview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
sgmntcontrol.frame = CGRectMake(50, 405,150 ,50)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get it to work this way. But as everything is in a xib why do I need to set the frames explicitly in code? Can't the dimensions and positions be picked up automatically from IB?

Comment: please mark this answer as accepted if its worked for you. according to me sometimes this problem was raised because of internal setting that's why we need to set frame for perfect designing.

Comment: No need to get so touchy, I was just about to ;-) So you don't know then basically. My problem is solved but I want to know iOS inside out and thus want to understand exactly why this is not working from IB alone.